# unable to reset root password of mysql

Tags: password, mysql, reset

I need to reset the root password of my local mysql installation but it woudln't let me. I've tried this:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                              [ OK ] 
[1]-  Exit 1                  sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
[2]+  Exit 1                  sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
reg@regDesktopHome:~$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 13651
reg@regDesktopHome:~$ 140627 19:02:02 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

reg@regDesktopHome:~$ mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
reg@regDesktopHome:~$ sudo mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

How can I get the password reset?
**edit 1**
I got this:

```
$ ps ax| grep mysql
16515 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
16551 pts/23   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios/v3upgrade$ sudo kill -9 16515
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios/v3upgrade$ ps ax| grep mysql
16678 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
16715 pts/23   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios/v3upgrade$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

looks like a process is automatically restarting mysql as soon as I kill it...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First please try using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and enter your password (if you remember) at the prompt to login as the sql-root user (note the switch `-p` is for password).

If you really have to reset your root password for mysql, here's an easy way - reconfigure the package with `dpkg-reconfigure`.

#### Easy steps to reset mySQL root password:

1. Check the version of your `mysql-server`;

   ```
   apt-cache policy mysql-server
   ```

   and see for the line which shows the installed version among other information. e.g. for my install it's:

   ```
   Installed: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
   ```

   (From this I know that I have `mysql-server-5.5` installed in my system.)
2. Start the reconfiguration with:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-*.*
   ```

   where `mysql-server-*.*` should be replaced by the version that you have. (for me it'd be `mysql-server-5.5`). This will stop the database daemon. A prompt will then appear where you'd have to enter your new password and confirm the reconfiguration.

   [image: snap1]

   The daemon will be automatically started after the reconfig completes.
3. You can then log in with:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

   and start your database admin tasks.

**References:**

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset [Which would soon be cleaned up as indicated in the page.]
2. [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/) related to your specific version.

Comment: Can confirm that `dpkg-reconfigure mariadb-server-10.1` worked for MariaDB when all other solutions didn't. Thank you for this.

Comment: Yes this worked - better to understand what is going on - Thanks rusty

Comment: Didn't work for me on 14.04LTS. What worked was: `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure` didn't prompt for password for me.. is there a way to force it?

Comment: Did not work for me. I used the command as above, and got "Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.13, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade". Using --force gave the same response.

Comment: Apparently this does not work anymore.

Comment: @AnthonyScaife did you get it? I have this same output.

Comment: @Paulo Henrique No. Given the situation, we decided the best use of our time was a full server reinstall.

Comment: @precise how do i can reconfigure with --force, because if i run your command to reconfigure, i am getting always  --  This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.19, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade

Answer (score 22):

[Reference taken from this blog:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/08/reset-mysql-root-password-ubuntu/)

Step 1:
Stop MySQL Service.

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Step 2:
Kill all running mysqld.

```
sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

Step 3:
Starting mysqld in Safe mode.

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Step 4:
Start mysql client

```
mysql -u root
```

Step 5:
After successful login, please execute this command to change any password.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Step 6:
You can update mysql root password .

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

**for mysql > 5.7 use this instead of above:**

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

Step 7:
Please execute this command.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Step 8:
Exit mysql console

```
exit
```

Step 9:
Kill mysqld_safe and start mysql

```
sudo killall mysqld_safe && sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: should be `sudo service mysql stop`, not `sudo stop mysql`

Comment: also, at the end it's missing the steps `sudo killall mysqld_safe && sudo service mysql start` and then try to log in again

Comment: For MYSQL 5.7 the change password syntax has changed to `ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED BY 'NEW_PASSWORD_HERE'`

Comment: **NOTE**! There is a new beast in MySQL 5.7 called auth_socket.  If you install mysql without a root password, the beast will attack you and you'll loose 50 hitpoints.  In step 6 above you need to ```ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'NEWPASS';```.  You can read about it [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/).  Theoretically (I didn't try), you should be able to log in to mysql without a password if you "sudo su -" to become root.

Comment: And in case ```ALTER USER ...``` doesn't work, use ```UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('NEWPASS'), plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';```

Answer (score 9):

Under Ubuntu 16.04 and `mysql-server-5.7`, the correct answer is the last comment of olafure, `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7` no longer works.

```sh
sudo service mysql stop
sudo killall mysqld
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root
```

Now in mysql console `>mysql`

```sql
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpass') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
\q
```

Restart the *good* `mysql` process

```sh
sudo killall mysqld
sudo service mysql start
```

Check your new password

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: newpass
mysql>
```

Comment: At `mysqld_safe` execution, I get the error: `Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.`. So I ran `sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld; sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld` and the rest of the above answer works. Is this a bug on Ubuntu 16? I've never experienced all these issues updating passwords before.

Comment: @Chester thank you very much!! This was the only way that finally worked now as all other solutions throw an error. (Ubuntu-Server 16.04 here)
This should be added to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Starting with **MySQL 5.7**, during initial installation, if you leave password empty, then for that user, authentication will be based on `auth_socket` plugin.

The correct way to change password will be:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
```

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/

Comment: This was my exact case (empty password during installation in mysql 5.7) and this was the only solution for my case.

Comment: I get the message: `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

Comment: @user2513149 Please restart your MySQL server without `--skip-grant-tables` option and see this solution works.

Comment: @Barun, no, without `--skip-grant-tables` option I can't even log into MySQL as root. It says `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: Solved! I had to login to regular MySQL console (not `mysqld_safe`) as root without password. I have Ubuntu 18.04 and mysql-server-5.7. This answer helped me https://askubuntu.com/a/767252/585252 (see the bottom part)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing from the rest of the answers seemed to work for me. This is my solution:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe &
sudo mysql -u root
```

In there:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
QUIT;
```

Then:

```
sudo killall mysqld
sudo service mysql start
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: The rest doesn't work for me neither ... nor does your solution unfortunately: Still get this Error

`2017-05-30T06:33:22.291126Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2017-05-30T06:33:22.294375Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-05-30T06:33:22.296874Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.`

Comment: This is the only advice that works for me out of the six or so suggestions I tried, but I added @Chester 's bit above to avoid the "UNIX socket file don't exists" error: `sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld; sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld` This is on mysql 5.7 and ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Stop the mysql server and run this:

```
mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```

Check here for more details:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html