# Trying to enter mysql prompt

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I have install MySql and now i am trying to get into the prompt of mysql with this command:

```
mysql -host localhost -p
```

but I am getting this error

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'ost' (2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your command line should be:

```
mysql --host=localhost -p
```

From the `mysql` man page:

```
   ·   --host=host_name, -h host_name

       Connect to the MySQL server on the given host.
```

Comment: this commands asks for password and after entering the pasword it gives this error
"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ifkaar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: @M.AhsenTaqi: Access to your database is a different problem. You should start a new question and close/accept this one. Try to look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/489098/unable-to-reset-root-password-of-mysql if you can't use your password.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ost was not defined in /etc/hosts (assuming that's what your using for -host based on error)

Would be something like

```
 ost     192.168.1.x
```

To be sure this is the problem, you can try to connect with ip address, rather than hostname and if that works, just edit

```
 /etc/hosts
```

As directed, with proper address