# mysql doesn't ask for root password when installing

Tags: software-installation, password, mysql, root

I used `apt install mysql-server` to install MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04 but during the installation, it did not ask for root password.

After installation I got `ERROR 1045` when I tried to login as `root` and `mysql_secure_installation` threw the same error. I `purge`d and `autoremove`d then reinstalled but it does not work.

How could i fix this? Can I set the root password if I didn't set it during installation?

This is my installation log:

> ```
> The following additional packages will be installed:
>   libaio1 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-server-5.7
>   mysql-server-core-5.7
> Suggested packages:
>   mailx tinyca
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   libaio1 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
>   mysql-server-core-5.7
> 0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 0 B/17,9 MB of archives.
> After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
> Preconfiguring packages ...
> Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:amd64.
> (Reading database ... 227144 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../libaio1_0.3.110-2_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-2) ...
> Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
> Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
> Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
> Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
> Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
> Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.12-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
> Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
> Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
> Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu4) ...
> Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
> Setting up libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-2) ...
> Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
> Checking if update is needed.
> This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.12, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
> Setting up mysql-server (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
> ```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can recover or set root password without knowing the current one by starting mysql without loading the grant-tables.

Please note the **`$`** in the commands.  This is specifying the terminal prompt you see when typing in the command.  It's showing it's a line of text, but and actual typed terminal command.  The "**`mysql>`**" prefix is also a prompt.  That is the prompt you get when running **mysql** interactivately.

This is the **cli** (command line) to do this:
*(Be sure to **stop the current server** before performing the steps.  Only one server can run at a time.)*

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld; sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables&
```

Now you can log in as root without a password and perform all commands, as in this case, set the root password as root.

```
$ sudo mysql --user=root mysql
```

This is the set root password that you will perform inside mysql if you have MySQL 5.6 or below:

```
mysql> update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
```

In MySQL 5.7 or above

```
mysql> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
```

From there, quit (kill the running msqld) mysql and start it as normal.

**Notes on starting and stopping the mysql service:**

Stop mysql:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
```

Start mysql (normal):

```
$ sudo service mysql start
```

Kill the temporary mysql safe mode session:

```
$ sudo mysqladmin shutdown
```

Comment: in mysql 5.7.12 there is no column named password in user table. Hence following command worked for me.
     update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';

Comment: I'm still getting `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi There are two things you should do.  Run `$ mysql_upgrade -u root -p`.  Also try the command above given by RP Singh .

Comment: I am also still getting this error.

Comment: ```SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('your-password')``` if you are using mariadb

Comment: before executing `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`, execute one more query: `UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password';` so that the MySQL server uses its native password plugin to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks much @Aryo. I was only able to login after `UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password'`

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL do not support the `PASSWORD` function.

Comment: For Mysql 8 -> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';

Comment: @makkasi `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

Answer (score 48):

It will not ask for the password while installing `mysql` in Ubuntu 16.04 but you can set it after successful installation in following way:

After completion of mysql installation, run command:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

It will show:

> NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
>         SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!
>
> In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
>   password for the root user.  **If you've just installed MariaDB, and you
>   haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank, so you
>   should just press enter here.**

`Enter current password for root (enter for none):` **(here press Enter)**

> OK, successfully used password, moving on...
>
> Setting the root password ensures that nobody can log into the MariaDB
>   root user without the proper authorisation.
>
> ```
> Set root password? [Y/n] y   (press 'y' to set new password)
> New password: 
> Re-enter new password:
> ```
>
> Password updated successfully! Reloading privilege tables..  ...
>   Success!

---

**For Ubuntu 18.04 OR `mysql-server` version 5.7.22, THIS METHOD WILL NOT WORK**

To set root password in Ubuntu 18.04, First follow the first three commands or first two steps of [L.D. James's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766900/mysql-doesnt-ask-for-root-password-when-installing/767252#766908) then run,

```
mysql> alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by '<password>';
```

Password for root user is set!

## OR

Follow these steps to set root password in 18.04:

As there is no password set for root user, simply login with [blank password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766900/mysql-doesnt-ask-for-root-password-when-installing/848504#848504)

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password: (press enter as no password is set)
```

after then can easily run query

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

Comment: The problem in the case of this question is that the user can't get to the prompts you're mentioned because he doesn't know the `current password for root`.

Comment: @L.D.James yes,you're right. I don't remember about ERROR : 1405 when i run `mysql_secure_installation` but `sudo mysql_secure_installation` worked for me. mysql installation doesn't ask for password. It happened with me the same. and `here press enter` means press enter without password.

Comment: As concers ubuntu 18.04 or debian 9+ it won't connect with blank password and even after resetting pass for root, it still refuses to connect

Comment: @chefarov Facing the same issue, intensely frustrating

Comment: Indeed, I still get the same error

Comment: It works, problem solved here with mysql-server v15.1 10.1.38-MariaDB

Comment: ` ... Failed! Error: SET PASSWORD has no significance for user 'root'@'localhost' as the authentication method used doesn't store authentication data in the MySQL server. Please consider using ALTER USER instead if you want to change authentication parameters.`

Answer (score 26):

After the installation just:

1. `sudo mysql`
   (yes, no user no pass)
2. You are now in the mysql console.
   Execute:

   `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'my_new_pass';`
3. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

That's it. You can now enter the console next time as usual:

```
mysql -u root -pmy_new_pass
```

Comment: I tried many other answers, but this one worked on Amazon EC2

Comment: This was the correct answer for WSL Ubuntu (Linux on Windows).

Comment: This is the only answer which worked for me on ubuntu 18.04 new installation on google cloud.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 19.04. I did run mysql_secure_myinstallation, but it seemed that the root password was not set.

Comment: I tried dozens of solutions.  This was the easiest and the only one that worked.

Comment: On your system, access to the MySQL `root` user is disabled through password, because password access on `root` simplifies brute forcing. So instead of enabling password access to root, I would rather recommend to create a new user with another username that is not easy to guess and grant all privileges on it so you can use it like root.

Comment: I tried all answers, not solve my solution, but this one. Using ubuntu 20.04 LTS and mysql 8.0

Comment: Finally!! It works!

Answer (score 24):

Apparently the mysql-server installation on 16.04 (or any 5.7 installation?) allows root access not through password, but through the [auth_socket](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/socket-authentication-plugin.html) plugin. Running `sudo mysql -u root` (n.b. w/o a password) will give you mysql console whereas running the command as non-root prompts you for a password.

It would seem that changing the password doesn't make much of a difference since the auth backend doesn't even check for a password. There is a very comprehensive article on how to [change the plugin and switch to password authentication](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/).

Comment: I was able to confirm with a fresh installation of `apt install mysql-server` without specifying a password on 18.04.  The symptom and solution is exactly as described.

Comment: so how the hell do i connect?

Comment: @JamieHutber change the authentication plugin to use by executing: UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password'; just before the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` so that it uses its native password plugin to authenticate.

Comment: confirmed on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 9):

1. there is a default user account.

   ```
   $ vim /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
   ```

   you will get this account from it like this:

   ```
   user     = debian-sys-maint
   password = nUZTARYslBsASzpw
   ```
2. you login with this account

   ```
   $ mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
   ```
3. edit you root password

   ```
   mysql> show databases；

   mysql> use mysql;

   mysql> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("new_password") where user='root';

   mysql> update user set plugin="mysql_native_password";

   mysql> flush privileges;

   mysql> quit;
   ```
4. restart mysql

   ```
   $ /etc/init.d/mysql restart;
   ```

then you can `mysql -u root -p` with you previous setting.

Comment: I tried every other solution, and this is the only one that worked for me. (Linux Mint 19.2).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the main answer, If you are stuck at

"*mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql*"

1 thing to remember that you have to use another terminal window to enter the following command.

```
$ sudo mysql --user=root mysql
```

If you try to do it in the same window, it will shut down the mysqld safemode process.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to setup `mysql-server` with a **terminal password prompt** in Ubuntu 18.10.

1. Download The MySQL APT Repository via https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/
2. `cd` into your directory where you downloaded and run `dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb` (check your version number)
3. From the prompt menu select the last option "ok" and then "ok" again.
4. Update and install mysql-server and mysql-client:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

5. Type in your root password in the promt.
6. Select `"Use Legacy Authentication Method"` if your running frameworks/applications (such as laravel) which do not support the new `"Strong Password Encryption"` yet, otherwise if your framework/application supports `"Strong Password Encryption"` then select it.
7. Login as root and check if it works.