# Installing LAMPP

Tags: lamp, xampp

I want to install the whole package of apache2, MySQL, PHP and phpmyadmin at a time on my ubuntu 14.04. I want to install the package from terminal. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by simply typing two commands.

- `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`
- `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

The first one will install `apache`, `php`, and `mysql` all at once. including all dependencies needed for phpmyadmin, and other web-apps. Then the 2nd will install & integrate phpmyadmin.

You will be prompted by both for setting up `mysql` credentials & giving such credentials for `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Thank you. It is easier. But I installed taskel first. As I didn't get this answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try and give you a good brief run down on how you can do this. Before starting do a system update:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` or

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

LAMP:

1. Linux:

   - installation of Ubuntu
2. Apache:

   - from the terminal run `sudo apt-get install apache2` or `sudo apt install apache2` if you installed Ubuntu 16.04 or higher.
   - to confirm apache is up and running:

     - open your browser of choice and go to this address in the address bar: `localhost/` and if it's installed you should see the image below

[image]

3. Mysql:

   - From the terminal run `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` or `sudo apt install mysql-server` if you installed Ubuntu 16.04 or higher
   - Follow the terminal instruction to add a **password**
   - Secure the installation by running this after the complete install:

     - `sudo mysql_secure_installation`
4. php:

   - Install with`sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql`

     - `libapache2-mod-php` allows apache parse php files
   - Run this `sudo systemctl restart apache2` to restart *apache* so its incorporates php parsing functionality, then check if its running with the next step
   - `sudo systemctl status apache2`, you should see the image below if its running

[image]

- Now php has many more modules that you can install. To see these by running this in the terminal `sudo apt-cache search php7` or `sudo apt search php7`

  5. phpmyadmin:

     - this can be installed with:
     - `sudo apt install phpmyadmin` or `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`. This will install the official package, but if this doesn't work get it from [here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/).
     - extract and drop it in `/var/www/html`. Change the folder name to _phpmyadmin__ and access it from the browser like this `localhost/phpmyadmin`

Now lets test your *apache* to see its working:

- from terminal run: `sudo vim /var/www/html/info.php`, and put this in that file, or use *nano* if you prefer!

  `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`

Open a browser and put this [localhost/info.php] into your address bar and  should see something like this:

[image]

**Note:** You can tweak your apache, mysql and php to suite your needs. This by no means all there is to setting up LAMP stack on your Ubuntu but its a start.

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: As in Feb,2020, (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS) everything is working fine with a few caveats: In step 3 the installation DOES **NOT** asks for a password, so I recommend to follow these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766900/mysql-doesnt-ask-for-root-password-when-installing). And in step 4 the `php-mcrypt` is deprecated and I simply remove it (there are some workarounds, but for now I just bypass it). And finally, if you'd like to use the gui to create files at `var/www/` I recommend [read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www). gl hf