# Mysql root password when install from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: mysql

I install MySql Server and MySql Client on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 from "Ubuntu Software Center".

As far as I know, when you install `mysql-server` from terminal, it prompt for `root` password in the middle of installation process. But when I install it from "Ubuntu Software Center", it just installed and I don't know what the `root` password is.

Comment: You can set the root password after installation. Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/766900/mysql-dont-ask-for-root-password-when-installing/767252#767252) answer

Comment: try runnig this `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and see if you'll be asked to put in a _password_ .

Comment: @daisy and George Great, thank you. Would any of you make that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: or make this question as duplicate, it is okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to stop/kill the existing mysql daemon, in case it is running:

```
 sudo  ps -ef | grep mysql      - checks if mysql/mysqld is one of the running processes.

 sudo kill -9 'pid' mysqld             - kills the daemon, if it is running.
```

Run MySQL safe daemon with skipping grant tables

```
 sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Login to MySQL as root with no password

```
 sudo mysql -u root mysql
```

Run UPDATE query to reset the root password

```
  UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("MyNewPassword") WHERE user="root";
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Stop MySQL safe daemon

```
 sudo  ps -ef | grep mysqld_safe 
 sudo kill -9 'pid' mysqld_safe
```

Start MySQL daemon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Privileges are flushed. Start MySQL and login as root with the password you reseted

```
 sudo mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Comment: This was really very helpful