# Reset Root Password for MySQL via Package Configuration

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I tried

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

I got this windows to allow me to reset my root password

[image]

---

How long should I wait after re-enter the confirmed password ?

Should I wait until it finished ?

As of now, I almost 2 mins :

## Result in CLI

**sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5**

```
170227 18:05:25 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170227 18:05:25 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
170227 18:05:25 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 11343 ...
```

---

After about 5 mins I got this screen

[image]

How do I fix it ?

Do I need to do anything to gain access back into my mysql as root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing and uninstalling mysql won't remove your database.  If you have a database it'll use what is there.

If you purge mysql and rename or remove the mysql configuration files you'll have an opportunity to perform a fresh install of mysql, whereas you can use a new password.

You have to have the password to access your current mysql database.

You asked **Do I need to do anything to gain access back into my mysql as root ?**.  The answer is yes.

You can change the password by running steps provided in this answer:
[mysql doesn't ask for root password when installing](https://askubuntu.com/a/766908/29012)

Comment: I did the first command of that link, and I got this `170227 18:45:00 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
170227 18:45:00 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
170227 18:45:00 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists`

Comment: Base on that when I did the second command `mysql -uroot` I kept getting
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: You have to first stop the current server that is running.  You can't start a new server (the -skip-grant-tables server) while the other server is running.  Shut down the current one with:  `sudo service mysql stop`  Then run the stops in the link.  Thanks for the info.  I'll add this, which I originally took for granted, to the other answer.

Comment: Ok. I'll stop my server now. How long will this command `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` take ? more than a minute ? It takes about 2 minutes now. Should I restart my entire server. I have a feeling that something went wrong.

Comment: It takes almost 4 mins now, is it hang  ??

Comment: It's probably not hanging... It's running.  Load a different Terminal and run the commands to connect to the server.  The server is running in the foreground.

Comment: I tried running on a different tab, I got `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` I got 
`170227 18:55:50 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
170227 18:55:50 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
170227 18:55:50 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists`

Comment: What did you type in the different tab?  Did you run this: `sudo mysql --user=root mysql`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54461/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-ihue).

Comment: I did `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`