# Problem while install mysql in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, mysql

I am trying to install MySQL in Ubuntu 18.04.

I used the command `apt-get install mysql-server`, but it did not ask for root password while installing.

I referred to the solution on this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766900/mysql-doesnt-ask-for-root-password-when-installing), but it shows error on this step `sudo mysql --user=root mysql`.

```
Error is `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`.
```

So I tried the top answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run), 
and when I checked, there was no `/etc/my.cnf` config file.

I also tried to reset the password using the answer by "davejal" on the previous link, but it gives the same error on this step `mysql -uroot`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the mysql service running?
Try

```
sudo service mysql status
```

There should see something like this on the third line

```
Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-09-06 13:29:28 CEST; 3s ago
```

If not, you can start the mysql service with

```
sudo service mysql start
```