# Failure to start MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using terminal

Tags: command-line, mysql

I am failing to start MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
`mysql -u root mysql` don't work and when I use `mysql -u root -p` , password is required but I didn't set a password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql doesn't ask for root password when installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766900/mysql-doesnt-ask-for-root-password-when-installing)