# Database connection error

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I never used Ubuntu, and now I installed Ubuntu 18.04, and I have a problem with connection to Database.

[image]

I'm not so familiar with the working with servers and things like that, so can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you able to start MySQL from terminal?

Comment: @Kulfy I only know to use this: service mysql status, it seems to work, and don't know what next nor how to fix it...

Comment: Try `mysql -u root -p` in terminal

Comment: @Kulfy it says:  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: It means you have provided wrong password and most probably in the given application too.

Comment: @Kulfy do I need to reinstall mysql? will then be fixed? or is it other way?
i'm sure i used correct one

Comment: No need to reinstall mysql. Try changing the password. If the password is correct then mysql wouldn't have denied the access. Try `mysql -u root`

Comment: @Kulfy ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)   :(

Comment: It mean that you've set a password that isn't blank. Also, you are entering wrong password. I'll suggest you to create new password. Refer this to reset password https://askubuntu.com/a/489132/816190

Comment: I tried it, but it's not worth it, then I reinstalled everything, and again the same error is displayed but now i can access mysql in terminal...

Answer (score 1):

Check that your mysql server is running, if not enable it. From a terminal,

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mysql

Synchronizing state of mysql.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql

$ sudo systemctl status mysql

● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-06-25 10:23:56 PDT; 56min ago
 Main PID: 1364 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 28 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─1364 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Check that you have it listen on port 3306.

```
$ sudo netstat -plunt

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1364/mysqld
```

If not, you'll have to modify `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Check that you have root access, enter password when prompted.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

If you don't have root access or need to reset root password, follow the steps from [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-reset-root-mysql-password-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux). Which basically says the simplest way is do the following and choose a new root password.

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
```

Now, if you want simply want to connect to a remote database, specify the host and port along with the login user/password when creating the mysql connection.

If you run into password validation problem, you may consider moving validate_password plugin

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> uninstall plugin validate_password;
```

Comment: i came to "three levels of password validation policy...", what should i do there? and how to specify the host? Sorry, but this is the firs time i'm doing this

Comment: Looks like you ran into the same problem as I did when I upgraded to 18.04. I have to uninstall validate_password plugin so that I can use my password. Otherwise it kept complaining it is not secure enough password for "online" login. I'll add some instruction to remove the plugin.

Comment: Yes, I've heard from a lot of people that they have errors since they were upgraded to 18.04, okay, I am waiting for instructions

Comment: In 18.04, they enable the security feature to protect remote login, i.e., connecting via host and port. So you need to re-enable that in order to use mysql the old way, which is the way that workbench connect to the database.